# Pass Variable After Calling Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have two issues.

1. Because Var3 can be blank sometimes depending on the Sub, I get a 424 error and the word 'undefined' is copied into the textbox on the website - however I need to leave it blank and not paste anything in this case.
2. I have a dropdown box in Excel to select what Sub will be called. I would like to incorporate this into an IF statement as shown below, but when I try the code, nothing happens.

Here is my attempt:

```
Public Sub Populate()

Dim Var1 As String
Dim Var2 As String
Dim Var3 As String    

Dim User_Name As String
Dim StrFile1 As String
Dim StrFile2 As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim strFilename As String

Dim IE As Object

If ComboBox1.Value = "Data1" Then
    Call Data1 (Filename, Var1, Var2, Var3)
End If

If ComboBox1.Value = "Data2" Then
    Call Data2 (Filename, Var1, Var2, Var3)
End If

'If ComboBox1.Value = Data3, Data4, etc...

    User_Name = Environ("UserName")
    StrFile1 = "C:\Users\"
    StrFile2 = "\Desktop\"

    strFilename = StrFile1 & User_Name & StrFile2 & Filename

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & strFilename, Destination _
        :=Range("$A$22"))
        .Name = Filename
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27

    DoEvents

    'FillInternetForm
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://website.com"
    IE.Visible = True
    While IE.busy
        DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
    Wend

    IE.Document.All(Var1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
    IE.Document.All(Var2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6")
    IE.Document.All(Var3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub


Public Sub Data1 (ByRef Filename As String, ByRef Var1 As String, ByRef Var2 As String, ByRef Var3 As String)

    Filename = "FILE1.CSV"
    Var1 = "Response123"
    Var2 = "Response456"
    Var3 = "Response789"

End Sub

Public Sub Data2 (ByRef Filename As String, ByRef Var1 As String, ByRef Var2 As String, ByRef Var3 As String)

    Filename = "FILE2.CSV"
    Var1 = "Response987"
    Var2 = "Response654"
    Var3 = "Response321"

End Sub

'Public Sub Data3, Data4, etc...
```

Comment: `Var` is a local variable accessible only from within the Populate sub. The Variable1 sub has no access to `Var`. If you are using the [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx) statement, your code shouldn't compile (even when correcting the `Dim` typo at the start. I suggest you to always use `Option Explicit`, and to use `Function` to return values instead of `Sub` and shared variables.

Comment: `" & Var & "` is a string constant, not code doing any concatenation. What do you want to concatenate `Var` with? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264104.aspx on how to use the `&`operator to concatenate.

Comment: Thanks Vincent G 50, I'm trying to replace the text box ID inside of the quotes "..." with a variable after IE.Document.All(" ... ").Value, but found using the &..& didn't work. Also typo was corrected - it wasn't spelled this way in my actual code :)

Comment: If I wanted to include calculations based on excel sheet values in Variable1()... would you still recommend making it a function instead of a sub? I'd like to use it to return values, but also make calculations and do other things.

Comment: See @Comintern answer. IMHO Function are the best wait to return a single value. When multiples values need to be returned, a Function or a Sub with ByRef parameters can be used equally. I can't think of anything done in a sub that cannot be done in a function.

Comment: I edited my original post here with an update showing new code to give a more accurate glimpse into what I'm trying to accomplish. However a couple new issues have come up that I can't seem to fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how variables work, and it isn't how parameters work.  As pointed out in the comments, variables declared inside procedures only have scope inside those procedures.  If you want to change the value outside of the procedure you're in from a different procedure you have 2 options - either pass them `ByRef`:

```
Sub Variable1(ByRef Var As String)
    Var = "R_575031"
End Sub

'In the calling code...
Variable1 Var
```

...or assign them to the return value of a function:

```
Function Variable1() As String
    Variable1 = "R_575031"
End Function

'In the calling code...
Var = Variable1
```

In your case, the second makes for clearer, easier to read code.

As for *using* it, this line is wrong:

> ```
> E.Document.All(" & strVar & ").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
> ```

You don't concatenate variables into commands.  If you need to pass a parameter, pass a parameter:

```
E.Document.All(strVar).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
              '^^^^^^ this is a parameter of .All()
```

Comment: Thank you Comintern, this was helpful. When I create a function As String, does that limit the use of the function to strings only? Basically I want to add more to this function such as make calculations, pass multiple variables, etc and not just use it for passing strings into variables. If this is the case, would you then suggest going with your first option using ByRef?

Comment: @RS - I'm not sure what you mean by "make calculations and not just use it for passing strings". But yes, if it returns a `String`, that's what it returns. Good design practices would only have each `Sub` or `Function` responsible for doing 1 thing though.

Comment: My plan is to have multiple functions/subs and when one is called have it perform a series of individual tasks. One task will involve selecting cells on an excel sheet and making calculations such as average, min, and max values, etc. For each function/sub the cell range will differ when making these calculations. The variable Var is just one result. There will  be multiple variables such as Var1, Var2, etc for each result and all will go into IE. Sorry I should have made this more clear in my original post. I will definitely post more detailed code in the future. I hope this is clear.

Comment: @RS - You can certainly use more than 1 'ByRef' parameter for either functions or subs ([see this page on Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/7363/passing-arguments-byref-or-byval#t=201701041526358654955)), but in general it would indicate poor design. If the variables are going to be used globally, declare them as globals.

Comment: I edited my original post here with an update showing new code to give a more accurate glimpse into what I'm trying to accomplish. However a couple new issues have come up that I can't seem to fix..

Answer (score 1):

If you Declare (DIM) a Variable within a subroutine/function, it is only available within that subroutine/function.

You need to declare the variables publicly for them to be available to other subroutines.

Alternatively, you could rewrite the code, as follows:

```
Private Sub Populate()

Dim strVar As String 
Dim IE As Object

DoEvents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Navigate "https://website.com"
    .Visible = True
    While .busy
        DoEvents  
    Wend
End With
strVar=Variable1()

IE.Document.All(" & strVar & ").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

End Sub

Private Function Variable1() AS String
    Var = "R_575031"
End Sub
```

By turning the routine into a function, you can return a value.  Private Functions only exist in the module (eg within a form).  Public Functions and subs belong in global module containers rather than in Form / Sheet containers.

Comment: Thanks I think I'll try making these subs public instead, only because I want to include other commands inside of Variable1() such as calculating averages from specific cells in the excel worksheet. The cell numbers for the calculations will also vary by each sub (ex. Variable 1(), Variable 2(), etc.)

Comment: Is it the same calculation being done lots of times?  I would move away from just giving the function names generic names - give it a name you would understand.